# I can't spread the width of 3 divs to full 100% of parents width in fluid design

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout

I got 3 divs which are meant to sit in one line. Their width is 33% each of the parent element. It seems like the 3 divs aren't stretching to 33% and only are as wide as the text in them.

How to make them be exactly 100% of the parent element (3x33%)?

Only having this problem because I'm working with fluid layout.

Here's link to [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2wB42/).

CSS

```
.page_block {
    max-width: 1000px;
    min-width: 600px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.foot_bar_links {
    float: left;
    width: 32%;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#foot_left {
    min-height: 230px;
    width: 68%;
    float: left;
}

#foot_right {
    min-height: 230px;
    width: 32%;
    float: left;
}

#foot_links1 {
    min-height: 80px;
    float: left;
}

#foot_links2 {
    min-height: 70px;
    float: left;
}

#foot_links3 {
    min-height: 60px;
    float: left;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="foot_bar_links">
    <div style="width: 50%">
        PROGRAMS<BR />EVENTS<BR />CALENDAR
    </div>
    <div style="width: 50%">
        <img src="images/calendar_s.jpg" style="vertical-align: middle">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="foot_bar_links">
    <div style="width: 50%">
        <b>STAY INFORMED</b> 
    </div>
    <div style="width: 50%">
    <img src="images/newspaper_s.jpg" style="vertical-align: middle">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="foot_bar_links">
    <div style="width: 50%">
        <img src="images/phone_s.jpg" style="vertical-align: middle">
    </div>
    <div style="width: 50%">
        ######
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i might have a feeling it might be because if min-width: 600px?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@HelpNeeder,
To place 3 divs in one line, Do this,

```
#div1, #div2, #div3{ position: relative; float: left; }
#div1{ position: relative; width: #Container-width/3 !important}
#div1{ position: relative; width: #Container-width/3 !important}
#div1{ position: relative; width: #Container-width/3 !important}
```

And the html

```
<div id='div1'>
    Div 1 contents goes here
</div>
<div id='div2'>
    Div 2 contents goes here
</div>
<div id='div3'>
    Div 3 contents goes here
</div>
```

Clear the floats by this

```
<div style='clear: both;'></div>
```

This will place three divs in one line

Comment: Ah! So all I was needing was keyword !important... Thanks.

Comment: @HelpNeedee keyword Not the keyword.

Comment: Using `!important` is never a good thing unless you have very good reasons to do so (overriding a third-party style that you have no control over, for example). That's a smell that you're fighting a css specificity war.

Comment: @gtramontina, I see your point there. I will be a looking a way around it today.

Answer (score 2):

Waaaay simpler solution ([JSBin](http://jsbin.com/jogiviqu/1/)):

HTML:

```
<article>
  <section>Bla bla bla.</section>
  <section>Bla bla bla.</section>
  <section>Bla bla bla.</section>
</article>
```

CSS:

```
article {
  display: flex;
}
```

Booom...

Answer (score 1):

In your stylesheet, under #foot_links2, replace:

```
float: left;
```

with

```
width: 100%;
```

Then replace everything under .foot_bar_links with

```
.foot_bar_links {
    float: left;
    width: 31%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.foot_bar_links:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

,
and see if that makes a difference. The use of

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

is also good advice.

Answer (score 0):

@HelpNeeder,
To be quite honest with you...I can't understand what your question is. Please be more specific when asking. But I can give you a little advice. After you float a div It's better to add

```
<div style='clear: both;'></div>
```

Div, It's then It will clear the last float column relative to the position.
When you have a question please don't put whole bunch of you code. Make a simple example and ask the question. Please edit the question and comment OK under this answer. I'm glad to help you then.

Comment: ok I'll paraphrase in my OP. My question is. how to make those 3 divs in one line, but none of them actually spreads to total of 100% of div element in which they sit in.

Comment: also cleared code, and added jsfiddle example. thanks